# How can I make an event for getting focus for double click on textbox? (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I have a textBox and I call an event get focus, when click on it. The behaviour  is different when I make a double click on it, how can I make an event for getting focus for double click on this textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *OnTap()* and *OnDoubleTap()* methods of the TextBox. And in each method you can define the different logic and set the focus on the TextBox.

**Update:**

Here's a simple code structure on how to make it work:

*XAML:*

```
<TextBox x:Name="InputTextBox" Margin="0,0,0,520" />
```

*C#*

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InputTextBox.Tap += InputTextBoxTap;
    InputTextBox.DoubleTap += InputTextBoxDoubleTap;
}

private void InputTextBoxDoubleTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    InputTextBox.Text = "Double tapped!";
}

private void InputTextBoxTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    InputTextBox.Text = "Tapped!";
}
```

I tested this on both the emulator and on a device and it works in both cases!

Comment: OnDoubleTap() methods doesn't invoke at all

Comment: Did you test this in the emulator or on a real device?

Comment: In Debud, it does't come in this methode, using emulator

Comment: Do you have your code right? See my updated answer for a working solution.

Comment: it work but not always, try to create a textbox, when It doesn't have a focus, it doesn't work, when I tap once and it get the focus it works

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple.

If you have notice the arguments supplied are different

```
private void textBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

}

private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Yes if you want them to resemble the same you can select "MouseClick" event from the properties.
Cheers!

Comment: That code is not for a TextBox in the Silverlight for Windows Phone version. Check MSDN: http://bit.ly/xYV58f

Comment: Yes, I don't have this event, it's a pity